# Get result of screen size to display in text field in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c

I think this is really easy but how do I get the result of screen size to display in a text field in Objective-C? I can get it in NSLog, like so:

```
CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
CGFloat screenHeight = rect.size.height;

NSLog(@"%f",screenHeight);
```

but not in a text field.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you know how to set the text of a text field? Do you know how to convert your `CGFloat` to an `NSString`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use stringWithFormat method to convert CGFloat to NSString , and can set to TextField.Code is fllow:

```
 CGRect rect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
 CGFloat screenHeight = rect.size.height;
 UITextField *textFiled = //------ some code----
 NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf",screenHeight];
 textFiled.text =str;
```

hope to help you.